# For which positive integers $n$, with $\gcd(n, 5) = 1$, is $n^4 + 4^n$ prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> For which positive integers $n$, with $\gcd(n, 5) = 1$, is $n^4 + 4^n$ prime?

I think I need to use $\mod{5}$ because $n^4\equiv1\mod{5}$ by Euler's Theorem. And, since $\gcd(n,5)=1$, we don't need to consider those positive integers $5k$ where $k\geq1$.  We have $n^4+4^n\mod(5)$ congruence to $2,0$. I don't see how to get further. The only I can see is $5$. Can someone give me a hint or suggestion to find the solution set. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4^n \equiv (-1)^n \mod 5$, so if $n$ is odd you get $n^4 + 4^n$ divisible by $5$ (and thus not prime unless $n=1$).  But if $n$ is even, $n^4 + 4^n$ is also even...

EDIT:  Without the constraint $\gcd(n,5) = 1$, there are still no other primes.
If $n \equiv 1 \mod 4$, $n^4 + 4^n = n^4 + 4 m^4 = (n^2 - 2 m n + 2 m^2)(n^2 + 2 m n + 2 m^2)$, where $m = 4^{(n-1)/4}$.
If $n \equiv 3 \mod 4$, $n^4 + 4^n = n^4 + 4^3 m^4 = (n^2 - 4 m n + 8 m^2)(n^2 + 4 m n + 8 m^2)$, where $m = 4^{(n-3)/4}$.

Comment: $5$ is the only solution

Comment: $5$ is the prime, not the value of $n$.

Comment: If we don't have $\gcd(n,5)=1$, does that change the solution set?

Comment: No, it wouldn't, since the constraint $\gcd(n,5) = 1$ wasn't used above to determine that $n = 1$ is the only case (which happened to satisfy $\gcd(n,5) = 1$).

Comment: The constraint was used. For $n=5$ $n^4+4^n$ is not divisible by 5.